# Android: lossless WEBP compression

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, webp, lossless

I am compressing an image in the WEBP-format with the following code:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, outputStream)
```

Although I am using highest quality-settings, it looks like the image is *not* compressed lossless but **lossy**.
Corresponding to the Android developer docs, it should be possible to compress WEBP-files lossless: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html

I am doing this on a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2 Kitkat. Furthermore I am using the highest SDK throughout in my project.

Has anyone got an idea, how to save bitmaps as lossless WEBP-images?

Comment: I haven't used WEBP, but is there a way you can use some other utilities (e.g., ImageMagick) to confirm, conclusively, that the image is being saved lossy rather than lossless? If I were a betting man, I'd guess that you are right and the media formats page is wrong, where there is no direct means to encode in WEBP in a lossless fashion. But, if I were in your shoes, I'd want to know for certain whether the image is being saved lossy or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am loading the image again in my application and there it can be seen that the pixels are not the same as the pixels before. If I do the same thing with PNG as compression algorithm it works fine, which means that I get exactly the same picture again. I am using exactly the same algorithm I am just changing from PNG to WEBP.

Comment: @CommonsWare ...furthermore many pixels have the same value after saving the image as WEBP which kind of indicates a lossy compression.

Answer (score 0):

> As of Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, a value of 100 results in a file in the
> lossless WEBP format. Otherwise the file will be in the lossy WEBP
> format.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat#WEBP

It seems lossless WebP compression is only available for devices with at least Android Q, by specifying WEBP_LOSSLESS as the compression format (or WEBP with quality 100).